# How to create multiple div tags

Tags: html, tags

I have created an image.... i have to place 15 div tags in a row (totally i have 8 rows) with transparent color next to one another on the image. when i hover the transparent div tags, another div tags should appear giving me a different message. Since i dont know flash i am trying to work with CSS and JQuery. Please give me an idea of how to do this??? Creating a single single div tags can do the work... but is there any other option to create multiple div tags....

[DIV TAGS]  ........ [DIV TAGS]

[DIV TAGS] ....... [DIV TAGS]

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery you can append a div to another one using `$('#div1').append( $('<div />') );`

So something like:

```
$('#div1').bind('mouseenter',function() {
 $(this).append( $('<div />', {
  // attributes for new div    
  }));
});
```

will add a div to div with id 'div1' when the mouse enters it. You'll probably need to check for the existence of a previously created div, unless you want then all over the place, and might want to remove them when the mouse leaves.